# Can you split a Dynamic UITableView into Sections?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to put a signifier between two different types of data being fed into my dynamic UITableView. Am I allowed to split the data into two sections or would I have to just feed in a non-userInteractionEnabled cell to mark the split? I cannot programmatically set the numberOfSections property. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: yes it is called grouped tableview put sections `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}` to your tableview , look at http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/

Comment: Why can't you set `numberOfSections`?

Comment: @SpaceDust, You should add it as an answer.

Comment: @SpaceDust You don't need a grouped style table to have more than one section. It may certainly be appropriate, but plain style tables can have multiple sections too.

Comment: @rmaddy good call. All I had to do was override numberOfSectionsInTableView and my prob was solved

Comment: @rmaddy yes you are right initial picture popped in my mind was with all headers sections heights labels and stuff bottom line is he is ok with number of sections :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is creating a grouped table view , make sure in your interface builder you chose grouped tableview option for your table view

then call grouped table view methods such as

```
// for sections I guess you want 2 sections 
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     if(section==0)
       return [yourdatasource count]; // make sure that each section is returned here
     if(section==1)
       return [anotherdatasource count];
}

// set header height of gropued tableview
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 60.0; // choose your height for each section
}
//set header section labels
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
}
```

my code is not tested,

Look at this http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/ for further info